# Latex drawing Argand Diagram with axes in terms of pi?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I am attempting to draw an Argand diagram, with a circle centred at (0, −16*π*), radius 16*π*.

The issues are that my diagram has the real and imaginary axes adjacent to the axis, but I would like the labels to be directly above the imaginary axis for Im and directly to the right of the real axis (currently it is appearing above the real axis. I also want to have the axes labelled in terms of pi so they go like −32*π*, −16*π*, 0, 16*π*, 32*π*.

Currently I haven't managed to get my axes in terms of *π*.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-32*pi,
    xmax=32*pi,
    ymin=-32*pi*i,
    ymax=32*pi*i,
    axis equal,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=Re\{$\mathcal{A}(s)$\},
    ylabel=Im\{$\mathcal{A}(s)$\},
    disabledatascaling]

\fill [opacity=0.2] (0,-16*pi) circle [radius=16*pi];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please add a small test document including the necessary packages etc.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, it's just simpler to use TikZ directly. It's not a plot after all.

The `x` and `y` key allows you to scale your *xyz* coordinate system. No need to get *π* involved here.

The ticks are drawn in the canvas coordinate system so that they don't scale with the *xyz* coordinate system. The same is true for extending the axes about 10pt in all directions.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mRe}{Re}
\DeclareMathOperator{\mIm}{Im}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, x=+1mm, y=+1mm] % π equals 1mm
% 1. The circle
\fill[gray!50] (down:16) circle[radius=16];

% 2. The axes
\path[->, at end] % axes
  ([xshift=-10pt]left:32) edge
    node[right] {$\mRe\{\mathcal A(s)\}$} ([xshift=10pt]right:32)
  ([yshift=-10pt]down:32) edge
    node[above] {$\mIm\{\mathcal A(s)\}$} ([yshift=10pt]   up:32);

% 3. The ticks
\foreach \j in {-32, -16, 16, 32}{
  \draw[shift=(right:\j)] (down:2pt) node[below] {$\j\pi$} -- (   up:2pt);
  \draw[shift=(   up:\j)] (left:2pt) node[left ] {$\j\pi$} -- (right:2pt); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could just draw it directly.  This one is done with `lualatex` using the built-in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) language.

[image]

You need to compile this with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
numeric pi; 72 pi = 288;   % this is an arbitrary scale, so that pi is drawn as 4pt

% define the axes
path real, imag;
real = (left -- right) scaled 36 pi;
imag = real rotated 90;

% fullcircle paths have unit *diameter*
path C; C = fullcircle scaled 32 pi shifted (0, -16 pi);
fill C withcolor 7/8[blue, white]; 

% add some labels -- not sure that zero is needed
for i=-32, -16, 16, 32:
  draw (origin -- 3 down) shifted (i*pi, 0); label.bot("$" & decimal i & "\pi$", (i*pi, -3));
  draw (origin -- 3 left) shifted (0, i*pi); label.lft("$" & decimal i & "\pi$", (-3, i*pi));
endfor

% draw the axes
drawarrow real; label.rt("$\mathcal{A}(s)$", point 1 of real);
drawarrow imag; label.top("$\mathcal{A}(s)$", point 1 of imag);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Follow the link at the top to learn more about MP.